# Excess power consumption in Dell laptop

Tags: dell, power-management

I have bought a new Dell laptop, with 6 GB RAM, running 64 bit Ubuntu 11.10. I have both Windows on one partition and Ubuntu on another partition. When I use Windows, battery lasts for more than 2 hrs but when I use Ubuntu, battery lasts only for a maximum of 1.5 hrs.

I have installed Powertop and it reported a whooping 32 Watts. Initially the complete list in the tunables column reported bad. Even when the toggled the complete list to good, it just reports 31 Watts again.

What can I do to get my power consumption below 10 Watts? Please help!

Comment: Only half an hour difference? You're in luck. 32 watts is not that much for a Dell laptop, it seems. My laptop uses the same amount of power.

Comment: Would you please tell us that are you getting the same issue with ubuntu 12.04 release or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some good amount of research I've found that this is a kernel bug specific to the hardware that I use. I think I just have to wait for the 12.04 release.

Answer (score 1):

Install tlp for ubuntu. From powertop find out which component has bad power management. Tune that component in tlp. [link](https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/wiki/TLP-Linux-Advanced-Power-Management)

I have only 12W power consumption in my dell latop